# In PyQt5, Why Signal can't connect a Slot in a external class?

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots

## Background

I'm using signals to implement MVC in PyQt5. There are many interfaces in one program. Each page has a corresponding controller, and all the controllers are finally put together.

## Question

My question is : I implemented the same slot function in four different places, but Why Signal can't connect a Slot in a external class ?

Here is dir tree:

```
error
├─ UI
│    └─ main_window.py
├─ control
│    ├─ controller.py
│    └─ login_control.py
├─ main.py
└─ model
       └─ model.py
```

## minimal runnable example

model.py:

```py
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "aaa"
        self.password = "aaa"
```

login_control.py:

```py
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, view, stu_id, stu_psd):
        self._view = view
        self._stu_id = stu_id
        self._stu_psd = stu_psd
        self.init()

    def init(self):
        # connect successfully
        self._view.login_signal.connect(self._view.login)
        # Connection failed  why ???
        self._view.login_signal.connect(self.login)

        # connect successfully
        self._view.login_signal.connect(login)

    # why this failed ???
    def login(self):
        print('222')

def login():
    print('333')
```

controller.py:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from model.model import Student
from UI.main_window import MainWindow
from control import login_control


class Controll(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self._app = QApplication([])

        self._stu = Student()

        self._view = MainWindow()
        self.init()

    def init(self):
        login_controller = login_control.Controller(self._view, self._stu.name, self._stu.password)
        # connect successfully
        self._view.login_signal.connect(self.login)

    def login(self):
        print('444')

    def run(self):
        self._view.show()
        return self._app.exec()
```

main_window.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLineEdit
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    login_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id_line = QLineEdit()
        self.id_line.setPlaceholderText("Please Input ID")
        self.psd_line = QLineEdit()
        self.psd_line.setPlaceholderText("Please Input Password")

        self.init()

    def init(self):

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button = QPushButton("Login")
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        layout.addWidget(self.id_line)
        layout.addWidget(self.psd_line)
    
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.login_signal)

    def login(self):
        print('111')

    def verify_ok(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Correct", "Login successfully")

    def verify_no(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Mistake", "Input again")
```

main.py

```py
import sys
from control.controller import Controll


if __name__ == "__main__":
    controller = Controll()
    sys.exit(controller.run())
```

`python main.py`, the output is:

```sh
111
333
444
```

The output which I want is:

```
111
222
333
444
```

I want to verify the info in `login` function. But why `222` is not output, and what should I do to fix it? This problem has bothered me for half a month, thank you.

Comment: Your structure is a bit convoluted. In any case, can you provide an *actual* reproducible code? There's no `main.py`, you only posted the code of `Controller` twice.

Comment: Sorry, I am going to do it.

Comment: In `Controll.init`, `login_controller` is a local variable. It will be garbage collected when `Controll.init` returns which will also delete the signal-slot connection to `login_controller.login`. One way to get around this is to make `login_controller` an instance variable of `Controll`.

Comment: Thank you !!! I solve it as your description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no persistent reference to `login_controller`: you create it as a *local* variable, then the `init` function returns, python's garbage collector is unable to find any reference to it, so it deletes it.

The solution is simple:

```
    def init(self):
        self.login_controller = login_control.Controller(
            self._view, self._stu.name, self._stu.password)
        self._view.login_signal.connect(self.login)
```

Please consider that, while using an MVC pattern is generally a good idea, it should be done to improve the quality of your project structure by providing better abstraction and offering easier debugging without overcomplicating things.
For instance, your `Controller` class (which also has a name that is really *too* similar to the other one), is almost superfluous, as your main `Controll` should be enough.