# PyQt5 slots confusion, can't connect unless using static or partial?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

I'm attempting to build a GUI using MVC and I'm trying to connect slots in the view class to signals in the UI class. The following doesn't work:

```py
def _test(self):
    print("Signal Connected")

def _connectSignals(self):
    # This is how I want to connect slots from the View class
    self.window.getButton.clicked.connect(self._test)
```

So then I tried a couple things I saw on stacked Overflow like:

- wrapping `@staticmethod` around the `_test` method
- Using a partial `self.window.getButton.clicked.connect(partial(self._test))`

Both of which worked, however this feels hacky and like it's bound to fail if I continue to expand the app this way.

I'm not sure what's the correct way to connect slots anymore.

I've also tried connecting the slot in the UI class instead of the view class and it actually worked fine, but I'd rather have the separation and would also like to know why this structure isn't working?

This [tutorial from RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/) effectively uses the MVC structure however they don't import the UI from a .ui file. Our code structure is almost identical minus the name changes.

This just further adds to the confusion that is PyQt5 Slots

[Similar Question but not the same format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026582/in-pyqt5-why-signal-cant-connect-a-slot-in-a-external-class)

**test.py -- GENERATED FROM PYUIC5**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 110, 211, 191))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.getButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.getButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 89, 25))
        self.getButton.setObjectName("getButton")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.getButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GET"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))
```

**test_app.py**

```py
from functools import partial
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

# Import QApplication and the required widgets from PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow
)

from test import Ui_MainWindow


class MttView(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """ View Class for the GUI"""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Setup the View within the Controller
        * Not standard but minimal code needed
        """
        super().__init__(parent=None)

        # Set up the Main Window from the .UI File
        self.setupUi(MainWindow=self)

        self._connectSlots()


    def _connectSlots(self):
        """
        Populates the serial combos with placeholders
        """

        # Connecting slot here works
        # self.getButton.clicked.connect(self._test)

    def _test(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.value}")



class InfoController:
    """ The Logic behind the app """

    def __init__(self, window: MttView):
        self.window = window
        self._connectSignals()

    # Uncommenting the following will work
    # @staticmethod
    def _test(self):
        print("Signal Connected")

    # Uncommening the following throws this error:
    #   TypeError: connect() failed between clicked(bool) and _test()
    # @pyqtSlot
    # def _test(self):
    #     print("Signal 2 connected")


    def _connectSignals(self):
        
        # [DOESN'T WORK] unless we use @staticmethod
        # What I want to do
        self.window.getButton.clicked.connect(self._test)

        # [WORKS] without @staticmethod
        # self.window.getButton.clicked.connect(partial(self._test))


def main():
    """ Main Function setting up the Application"""
    mtt = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Show the MTT GUI
    view = MttView()

    # Connect the Controller
    InfoController(window=view)

    view.show()

    # Execute the main loop of the application
    sys.exit(mtt.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Change to `ctrl = InfoController(window=view)`. The key is the scope of the variables, partial makes the controller have a scope so it will not be deleted. The same for staticmethod

Comment: WOW! THANK YOU! Python is touchy in that regard! I followed the tutorial from RealPython and it doesn't assign the view to a variable, yet it still works for them